# Does the sample size influence the number of PCs needed to explain a fixed percentage of variance?

Tags: variance, pca, references, sample-size, covariance-matrix

In PCA, I have observed the following pattern: larger sample sizes from the same population(s) imply that a higher number of principal components (PCs) are required to explain a fixed percentage of variance.

Using an anecdotal example, if I have a sample size of 100, then 10 PCs explain 90% of the variance. However, if I have a sample size of 200, then 20 PCs may be required to explain the same 90% of variance.

My questions are:

1. Does this pattern hold generically for all kinds of data?
2. If the answer to the previous question is "yes", then is there any literature reference I can use to make such claim? (I've searched but didn't find any).
3. If the answer to the previous question is "no", is there a simple rational I can use to explain why this pattern occurs?

Comment: For random sampling with $n\gg p$, the proportion explained by $k$ components should converge toward a constant as $n$ grows, but in finite samples it will have an upward bias.that relates to $p/n$ (that is if $p/n$ is large it will have a higher upward bias in proportion of variance). So you would expect to see it, but the size of the effect should typically be weaker at relatively larger sample sizes (for similar structure in the variables).

Comment: In my case I have $n \ll p$. More specifically I'm experimenting with sample sizes between 30<n<100 and p=4000 variables. @Glen_b, your description is in accordance with my observations, but is there any reference/article/book which I can use to make such a statement? I think making that statement in an article would require a reference, but it's such a specific issue that I can't find any. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know a reference for it, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably in the $n\ll p$ situation. As @Glen_b wrote in the comment above, such a behaviour is expected.

### Illustration and intuition

Let $p=1000$. Let the population be a multivariate normal with mean zero and some arbitrary covariance matrix $\boldsymbol\Sigma$. Let us sample $n$ points from this population and compute the sample covariance matrix $\mathbf S_n$. Here I plotted the spectrum (sorted eigenvalues) of $\boldsymbol\Sigma$ (black line) and the spectra of $\mathbf S_n$ for various values of $n$:

[image: Spectra for various n]

The sum of all eigenvalues (trace of $\mathbf S_n$) remains approximately constant because it is equal to the sum of variances of each of the $p$ variables, and those can be reasonably well estimated already with small $n$: $$\operatorname{tr}(\mathbf S_n)\approx \operatorname{tr}(\boldsymbol\Sigma).$$ But if $n=100$, then certainly only $100$ eigenvalues can be non-zero, so the same trace has to be "spread" over only $100$ values, meaning that the leading eigenvalues will be much larger than the population ones. As $n$ grows, the leading eigenvalues will decrease and the tail will grow. Notice that even once $n>p$, the bias still remains and only with $n=10000$ (ten times the dimensionality) the spectrum starts to look like the population spectrum.

The dots mark the number of components that explain $90\%$ of the variance. The more horizontal the spectrum looks, the larger this number, so by now it should be clear that it will increase with increasing $n$.

For clarity, here is the same example with $\boldsymbol\Sigma = \mathbf I$. The same effect can still be clearly observed:

[image: Spectra for various n, spherical covariance]

### Theory

If $\mathbf x \sim \mathcal N (0, \boldsymbol \Sigma_{p\times p})$, then $$(n-1) \mathbf S_n \sim \mathcal W_p(\boldsymbol \Sigma, n-1),$$ where $\mathcal W$ is [Wishart distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution). Wishart distribution is well studied, so I expect that there are results about the sampling properties of the eigenvalues of Wishart-distributed matrices. I am not familiar with this field so I cannot say much more, but this would be a starting point for further exploration.

### References

I think you might want to cite Jollife, 2002, *Principal Components Analysis*, section 3.6 "Probability Distributions for Sample Principal Components". Here is what he writes there, page 48 ($l_i$ denote eigenvalues of $\mathbf S_n$  and $\lambda_i$ denote eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol \Sigma$):

> One specific point [...] is that $E(l_1 ) > \lambda_ 1$ and
>   $E(l_p ) < \lambda_p$. In general the larger eigenvalues tend to be overestimated and the smaller ones underestimated.

He also adds that

> If a distribution other than the multivariate normal is assumed, distributional results for PCs will typically become less tractable.

The references given around are Jackson, 1991, *A User’s Guide to Principal Components* and Srivastava and Khatri, 1979, *An Introduction to Multivariate Statistics*. I am not familiar with these books.

Note that Jolliffe does not explicitly comment on the fact the you need more PCs to explain a certain percentage of variance. But perhaps you can write something like that:

> For smaller $n$ less PCs are needed to explain the same amount of variance because for smaller $n\ll p$ leading eigenvalues tend to be overestimated and trailing eigenvalues underestimated (Jollife 2002, Section 3.6).

---

### Matlab code to produce these figures

```matlab
clear all
p = 1000;
ns = [100 200 500 1000 5000 10000];

W = randn(p,p);
Sigma = transpose(W)*W;
%// alternatively: Sigma = eye(p);
spectrum_population = sort(eig(Sigma), 'descend');

figure('Position', [100 100 1000 400])
hold on
col = lines(length(ns));

for i = 1:length(ns)
    X = randn(ns(i),p);
    X = X * chol(Sigma);
    spectra(i,:) = sort(eig(cov(X)), 'descend');

    h(i) = plot(spectra(i,:), 'Color', col(i,:));
    ind = find(cumsum(spectra(i,:)) > 0.9*sum(spectra(i,:)), 1);
    plot(ind, spectra(i,ind), '.', 'MarkerSize', 20, 'Color', col(i,:))

    leg{i} = ['n = ' num2str(ns(i))];
end

h(length(ns)+1) = plot(spectrum_population, 'k', 'LineWidth', 2);
ind = find(cumsum(spectrum_population) > 0.9*sum(spectrum_population), 1);
plot(ind, spectrum_population(ind), 'k.', 'MarkerSize', 20)
leg{length(ns)+1} = 'Population';

legend(h, leg)
legend boxoff 
axis([0 p 0 max(spectra(:))])
```

Comment: Amoeba thanks for your answer. If, in the next few days, nobody can suggest a reference (which I would prefer), I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I updated my answer with a possible reference.

Comment: That's a great answer, thanks! I actually have that book, and searched for answers there, but the issue is, has shown by your answer, a bit more subtle. Answer accepted. Thank you once again!

Comment: Thanks for the interesting question too. It's a pity that it gets so few views here (questions about multivariate analysis rarely attract much attention).